# Log REST request using org.apache.wink RequestHandler

Tags: rest, handler, apache-wink, requesthandler

I have a requirement to log the REST request and response messages, so I have used apache wing RequestHandler. And I am able to get the response using the ResponseHandler. But unable to get the Request details in Handler Class. Could you please help me on this?

```
public class RESTRequestHandler implements org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandler {

@Override
    public void handleRequest(MessageContext context, HandlersChain handlerChain)
            throws Throwable {
        //Unable to fetch the request details..Issue is here
        handlerChain.doChain(context);
            }

}

public class RESTResponseHandler implements org.apache.wink.server.handlers.ResponseHandler {
@Override
    public void handleResponse(MessageContext context, HandlersChain handlerChain)
            throws Throwable {
//Able to get the response details using the below code
   SampleResponseObject object=(SampleRespObject) context.getResponseEntity();
            }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting while fetching the request?